# Email Two-Factor Authentication on FortiGate

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

I'm currently implementing Multi-Factor Authentication on FortiGate, using mailer system and refer to this document [link](https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD45585#:%7E:text=NOTE%3A%20Email%20based%20two%2Dfactor,as%20usual%20during%20access%20attempt).

There is no options to change the subject or content of email, because currently the subject looks like `Authcode: {number}` and the content `Your authentication token code is XXXXXX`.

Is it possible to change that? is there any  way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that FortiGate firmware image is just around 60 MB (estimated [from 6.0.6](https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD46352)) with all the features it has. One of the reasons is that they have focused on the security features more than the appearance – like customizable 2FA email templates. As such feature is not documented to be configurable in GUI nor CLI, it is very unlikely there would be one.

If you absolutely need to modify the email contents, you could add some external email gateway that beautifies the messages. But is it necessary? It's just an authentication token, and something the receiver would expect to get without need for additional explanations in the message.